# Inconsistent visited & consecutive days

Tags: bug, status-completed

I think the problem which was marked as status-completed in [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54681/inconsistent-consecutive-days) still remains for Web Apps. Here is a screeny from my Web Apps profile. It shows **6** visited days with **6** consecutive, but I'm a member for **4** days. My visited and consecutive days cannot be more than 4. This is wrong.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for pointing this out - it will be fixed in tonight's build.